# grunt js is not compressing all scss files in to one css

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I am new in grunt, I was trying to compile scss file to css with the help of grunt js. my folder structures are for project is below-

```
public
|  |_css
|  |
|  |_sass
|    |_style.scss
|
gruntfile.js
package.json
```

my grunt file is.

```
// Load Grunt
module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

// Tasks
sass: { // Begin Sass Plugin
dist: {
files: {
'public/sass/**/*.scss': 'public/css/style.css'
}
}
},

watch: { // Compile everything into one task with Watch Plugin
css: {
files: './public/sass/**/*.scss',
tasks: ['sass']
},

}
});
// Load Grunt plugins
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

// Register Grunt tasks
grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

when i run grunt command i is not creating any compiled css file.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax on grunt-contrib-sass task is wrong. It should be 'destination' : 'src'

from

```
'public/sass/**/*.scss': 'public/css/style.css'
```

to

```
'public/css/style.css': 'public/sass/**/*.scss'
```

refer - example
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass

Update:

You shoudn't add underscore before _style.scss, files starting with _ wont be generated to the output. This is to avoid sass to generate the import files. Rename _style.scss to style.scss

Comment: After doing the chages, The style.css file is not creating. My logs are.
**Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "public/sass/_style.scss" changed.
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task

Done.
Completed in 0.633s at Thu Jun 22 2017 15:07:45 GMT+0530 (IST) - Waiting...
**

Comment: @MAKAM : You shoudn't add underscore before _style.scss, files starting with _ wont be generated to the output. This is to avoid sass to generate the import files